# finding the data of time between 2 columns times

Tags: vb.net

i have data like this

```
no_shift   start_time   end_time 
1          08:00:01     15:00:00
2          15:00:01     20:00:00
3          20:00:01     03:00:00
4          03:00:01     08:00:00
```

i am using this syntax:

```
select * from shift_time where `20:15:22` between start_time and end_time
```

i got null.. but if i changed the value to
`08:01:22` return 1
`16:35:12` return 2
`05:11:23` return 4

but if `22:02:22` i got null. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Consider carefully how **between** works - if `...X between A and B...` is synonymous with "A < X and X < B" then you won't ever have a hit where `no_shift` is 3 - which is where the times you're failing on fall, as 20:00:01 is not earlier (less than) 03:00:00. (You're not accounting for the change-of-day.)

Comment: This question has not much to do with vb.net and more to do with tsql

Comment: Save the Date along with the time, so you can compare Dates. You can then use just the Time part, if you need to format it.

Comment: @jimi : i have another table to save value with date and time but in the same time before saved data i want to check what shift the time is stored.

Comment: @jeff zeitlin : ooh ok i know it now the problem is end time was 03:00:00 so how to solved this probl or how to add value to 24 hours ?

Comment: It should not be difficult to work around the problem; the key will be checking whether the end-time of the shift is less than the start time of the same shift, and changing your processing based on that.